# alinear menus de izquierda a derecha

Tags: html, css

Tengo estos menus, que quiero que se alineen de izquierda a derecha pegados a la palabra que esta al lado de la imagen (SAE)

```css
.dropdownmenu ul, .dropdownmenu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropdownmenu ul {
    background: gray;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdownmenu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
}
.dropdownmenu a {
    background: #0c66a2;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font: 8px/8px sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
.dropdownmenu li:hover a {
    background: #28a745;
}
#submenu {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
li:hover ul#submenu {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 40px;  /* adjust this as per top nav padding top & bottom comes */
    visibility: visible;
}
#submenu li {
    float: none;
    width: 200%;
}
#submenu a:hover {
    background: #28a745;
}
#submenu a {
    background-color:#28a745;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark2">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <font size="1">SAE || SISTEMA DE ADMINISTRACION ENLACE</font>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <!--<a href="http://pacos.itink.info/">Cerrar Sesion <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> --> 
      <nav class="dropdownmenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index2.php">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PACOS</a>
            <ul id="submenu">
              <!--<li><input type="button" id="pack" class="btn" and style="background-color:transparent">PACOS EXISTENTES</li>-->
              <li><a href="index.php">AÑADIR NUEVO</a></li>
              <li><a href="pagoparcial.php">PACOS PAGO PARCIAL</a></li>
              <li><a href="liberar.php">LIBERAR PACO</a></li>
              <li><a href="nocerrado.php">PACOS GUARDADOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="asignarpaco70.php">ASIGNAR OS A PACO</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">REPORTES</a>
            <ul id="submenu">
              <li><a href="despa.php">CONSOLIDADO DE PACOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="pagados.php">PACOS PAGADOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="pagados.php">PACOS COMPARTIDOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="autorizar.php">PACOS PENDIDNTE AUTORIZAR</a></li>
              <li><a href="ppago.php">PACOS PENDIENTES DE PAGO</a></li>
              <li><a href="pfactura.php">PACOS PENDIENTES DE FACTURA</a></li>
              <li><a href="rfacpa.php">FACTURAS PAGADAS</a></li>
              <li><a href="fpp.php">FACTURAS PENDIENTES DE PAGO</a></li>
              <li><a href="asignarpaco70.php">OS SIN PACO</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </nav>
    </div>
  <a href="http://pacos.itink.info/" class="btn btn-success">Cerrar Sesion</a>
```

[image: Asi es como se ve y busco que esten a la izquierda]

Comment: estás con algún framework de css?

Comment: Creo que si amigo, acabo de tomar este proyecto y tengo que hacer eso, apenas voy descubriendo lo que hace

Comment: tienes la página en linea para ver con mayor detalle?

Answer (score 0):

Revisa si esto se aproxima a lo que deseas... *Ver snnipet en pagina completa*

Debí agregar la dependencia de Bootstrap, eliminé el primer botón y cerré varias etiquetas que tienes abiertas.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
      .dropdownmenu ul, .dropdownmenu li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .dropdownmenu ul {
        background: gray;
        list-style: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .dropdownmenu li {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width:auto;
    }
    .dropdownmenu a {
        background: #0c66a2;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: block;
        font: 8px/8px sans-serif;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
        -o-transition: all .25s ease;
        transition: all .25s ease;
    }
    .dropdownmenu li:hover a {
        background: #28a745;
    }
    #submenu {
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 35px;
        visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    li:hover ul#submenu {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 40px;  /* adjust this as per top nav padding top & bottom comes */
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #submenu li {
        float: none;
        width: 200%;
    }
    #submenu a:hover {
        background: #28a745;
    }
    #submenu a {
        background-color:#28a745;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark2">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><font size="1">SAE || SISTEMA DE ADMINISTRACION ENLACE</font></a>
        <nav class="dropdownmenu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index2.php">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PACOS</a>
              <ul id="submenu">
                <!--<li><input type="button" id="pack" class="btn" and style="background-color:transparent">PACOS EXISTENTES</li>-->
                <li><a href="index.php">AÑADIR NUEVO</a></li>
                <li><a href="pagoparcial.php">PACOS PAGO PARCIAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="liberar.php">LIBERAR PACO</a></li>
                <li><a href="nocerrado.php">PACOS GUARDADOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="asignarpaco70.php">ASIGNAR OS A PACO</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">REPORTES</a>
              <ul id="submenu">
                <li><a href="despa.php">CONSOLIDADO DE PACOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="pagados.php">PACOS PAGADOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="pagados.php">PACOS COMPARTIDOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="autorizar.php">PACOS PENDIDNTE AUTORIZAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="ppago.php">PACOS PENDIENTES DE PAGO</a></li>
                <li><a href="pfactura.php">PACOS PENDIENTES DE FACTURA</a></li>
                <li><a href="rfacpa.php">FACTURAS PAGADAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="fpp.php">FACTURAS PENDIENTES DE PAGO</a></li>
                <li><a href="asignarpaco70.php">OS SIN PACO</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="http://pacos.itink.info/" class="btn btn-success">Cerrar Sesion</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```